# Change values in cells if cell has -* at the start and * at the end

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy

I have a data frame that looks like this

```
Name     salary    age    Id
Steve    23000    -*29*   22
Mark    -*2900*    24     82
John     40000     26   -*72*
```

I would like

```
Name     salary    age    Id
Steve    23000     29     22
Mark     2900      24     82
John     40000     26     72
```

I have tried.

```
df.apply(lambda x:x[2:-1] if x.str.startwith('="') and x.str.endwith('"') else x)
```

I am getting error

```
ValueError: The truth of a series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()
```

I think I am not reaching the cells, instead I am applying the changes to the column.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you want to remove the `-*` characters:

```
df = df.apply(lambda c: c.str.strip('-*'))
```

output:

```
    Name salary age  Id
0  Steve  23000  29  22
1   Mark   2900  24  82
2   John  40000  26  72
```

*NB. your cells will still be strings, to convert to numbers:*

```
df = df.apply(lambda c: pd.to_numeric(c.str.strip('-*'), errors='ignore'))
```

Comment: It is like this -*29* I would like 29 it's not -*29

Comment: Your code will take off the first part -* not the last *

Comment: @Let'sbecool it will remove both, `strip` works on both ends. Have you tested it?